!!! FAIL serialization: cannot pickle 'EnhancedModule' object. Problem: Ray Serialization
I've been running a Python task on Ray Cluster and AWS. I have some custom classes and functions and can't get past serialization.
Receiving such errors:
!!! FAIL serialization: cannot pickle 'EnhancedModule' object
        Serializing '_function' <function preprocessing_video at 0x7f42bcc8edc0>...
        !!! FAIL serialization: cannot pickle 'EnhancedModule' object
        Detected 1 global variables. Checking serializability...
            Serializing 'Video' <__main__.ActorClass(Video) object at 0x7f42b8a1e970>...
            !!! FAIL serialization: cannot pickle 'EnhancedModule' object
        Serializing '__generator_backpressure_num_objects' None...`

Here's the function I want distributed:
@ray.remote
def store_all_videos_and_captions_from_urls(urls, args=None):
    import yt_dlp as youtube_dl
    channels = Channels().remote()
    """Download all Videos. Absolute main function.

    Args:
        urls (_type_): All YouTube URLs.
        output_folder (_type_): Where to save the videos
        args (_type_, optional): ArgParse args. Defaults to None.
    """
    for url in urls:
        if '@' in url:
            channel_id = url.split('@')[-1]
            
            # Init channel
            channel = channels.get_channel_by_id(channel_id=channel_id)
            if channel is None:
                channel = Channel.remote(url=url, channel_id=channel_id, args=args)
            
            channels.add_channel(channel)
            videos = channel.get_videos_from_channel.remote()
            
            # Go through all videos in a given channel
            for video in videos:
                if not channel.stop_processing:
                    preprocessing_video.remote(video=video, channel_id=channel_id, args=args)
                else: break
        else:
            preprocessing_video.remote(url=url, args=args)`

I tried assigning the @ray.remote decorator to functions and classes. Without success.
